# Conexión MQTT entre dispositivo GSM y AWS

Tags: arduino, mqtt

soy estudiante en practica y actualmente me encuentro trabajando con IoT, lo cual no había hecho antes. En resumen es lo siguiente:

Necesito realizar la conexión entre un dispositivo GSM (programable y no programable) al servicio AWS EC2, revisando documentación logre la creación de la instancia Linux con su respectiva configuración (en la capa gratuita), posteriormente instale el Broker de Mosquitto & Mosquitto_clients para realizar la conexión.

Una vez hecho eso, realicé la creación de un objeto en AWS IoT Core con sus respectivas credenciales, certificados y políticas asociadas con la finalidad de obtener el endpoit de conexión provisto por el sistema. Lamentablemente, no ha sido posible realizar la conexión de este en ningún caso, por esa razón ruego que alguien pueda ayudarme o guiarme en como debería rehacerla de forma correcta.

Sin nada, muchas gracias.

Pd: adjunto documentación pertinente al problema y considerar que desconozco gran parte de esto.

[Código utilizado en Arduino]

```
// modem:
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800

// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
// Use Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro
//#define SerialAT Serial3

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SerialAT(7, 8); // RX, TX

// See all AT commands, if wanted
//#define DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
// Define the serial console for debug prints, if needed
//#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon
// Range to attempt to autobaud
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN 9600
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX 115200

// Add a reception delay - may be needed for a fast processor at a slow baud rate
//#define TINY_GSM_YIELD() { delay(2); }
// Define how you're planning to connect to the internet
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false

// set GSM PIN, if any
#define GSM_PIN ""

// Your GPRS credentials, if any
const char apn[] = "bam.entelpcs.cl";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

// MQTT details
const char* broker = "yourBrokerConnection";
const char* topicLed = "GsmClientTest/led";
const char* topicInit = "GsmClientTest/init";
const char* topicLedStatus = "GsmClientTest/ledStatus";
const char* topicPing = "GsmClientTest/ping";

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
PubSubClient mqtt(client);

#define LED_PIN 13
int ledStatus = LOW;
long lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
long lastPing = 0;
unsigned long t;

void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {
    SerialMon.print("Message arrived [");
    SerialMon.print(topic);
    SerialMon.print("]: ");
    SerialMon.write(payload, len);
    SerialMon.println();

    //Only proceed if incoming message's topic matches

    if (String(topic) == topicLed) {
        ledStatus = !ledStatus;
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus);
        mqtt.publish(topicLedStatus, ledStatus ? "1" : "0");
    }
}

boolean mqttConnect() {
    SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
    SerialMon.print(broker);

    // Connect to MQTT Broker
    boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientTest");

    // Or, if you want to authenticate MQTT:
    //boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientName", "mqtt_user", "mqtt_pass");
    if (status == false) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        return false;
    }

    SerialMon.println(" success");
    mqtt.publish(topicInit, "GsmClientTest started");
    mqtt.subscribe(topicLed);
    return mqtt.connected();
}

void setup() {
    // Set console baud rate
    SerialMon.begin(9600);

    delay(10);

    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

    // !!!!!!!!!!!
    // Set your reset, enable, power pins here
    // !!!!!!!!!!!
    SerialMon.println("Wait...");

    // Set GSM module baud rate
    // TinyGsmAutoBaud(SerialAT,GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN,GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX);
    SerialAT.begin(9600);

    delay(300);

    // Restart takes quite some time
    // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()

    SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");

    modem.restart();

    // modem.init();

    String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
    SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");

    SerialMon.println(modemInfo);
#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS

    // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN if needed
    if (GSM_PIN && modem.getSimStatus() != 3) {
        modem.simUnlock(GSM_PIN);
    }
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
    // The XBee must run the gprsConnect function BEFORE waiting for network!
    modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);
#endif

    SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
    if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
    }
    SerialMon.println(" success");
    if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
        SerialMon.println("Network connected");
    }
#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
    // GPRS connection parameters are usually set after network registration
    SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
    SerialMon.print(apn);
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
    }
    SerialMon.println(" success");
    if (modem.isGprsConnected()) {
        SerialMon.println("GPRS connected");
    }
#endif
    // MQTT Broker setup
    mqtt.setServer(broker, 8883);
    mqtt.setCallback(mqttCallback);
}

void loop() {
    t = millis();
    if (!mqtt.connected()) {
        SerialMon.println("MQTT not connected");
        // Reconnect every 10 seconds
        if (t - lastReconnectAttempt > 10000L) {
            lastReconnectAttempt = t;
            if (mqttConnect()) {
                lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
            }
        }
        delay(100);
        return;
    } else if (t - lastPing > 60000L) {
        lastPing = t;
        mqtt.publish(topicPing, "ping");
        t = millis();
    }
    mqtt.loop();
}
```

Comment: "No ha sido posible realizar la conexión en ningún caso"... teniendo en cuenta que no tengo acceso al dispositivo para probarlo yo mismo, podrías ser un poco más específico??? Qué problema exacto tienes? Te da algún error? Has intentado algo más? No estamos a tu lado, ergo no podemos ver el problema... tenemos que ayudarte unicamente por lo que nos dices!